# mongoose $gte and $lte not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ecmascript-6

lately I have been developing an application where i need to get documents that are inside a specific location based radius. when I send the latitude and longitude to the server, my code properly calculates the minimum and maximum latitude and longitude. I try to put the calculated numbers inside $gte and $lte in mongoose query, but the expected results wouldn't show up!

I have tried the following mongoose query:

```
{ name: /^انار0$/i }
```

and I have got the following response:

```
[
{
    "rating": {
        "average": 0,
        "count": 0
    },
    "location": {
        "latitude": 33.635,
        "longitude": 70.889
    },
    "status": "ONLINE",
    "_id": "5c62fa691fab8f24209f36e6",
    "name": "انار0",
    "_type": "CAFE"
}
]
```

but when I send location and the query turns into the following:

```
{ location:
    { latitude:
        { 
            '$gte': 33.626016646154675,
            '$lte': 33.64398335384532
         },
     longitude:
         { 
             '$gte': 70.88152061196703,
             '$lte': 70.89647938803296
          } 
      },
      name: /^انار0$/i
}
```

I get an empty jsonarray as my response, where the response should not be different with the former query!

here is my code:

```
let query = {};
if (location.lat && location.lng){
    /**
     * earth radius is approximately 6378 kilometers
     * so each degree is 111.3170 km based on the (2*Pi/360) * 6378
     * basically each degree is 111317 meters
     * if we want shops in a 1000 meter radius then 1000 meters in degree would be 1000 / 111317
     */
    let Pi = Math.PI;
    if (isNaN(radius)) {
        radius = 1000; // radius in meters
    }
    let radiusInDegrees = radius / 111317;

    let locationQuery = {};
    locationQuery.latitude = {};
    locationQuery.longitude = {};

    locationQuery.longitude.$gte = location.lng - (radiusInDegrees * Math.cos(location.lat * (Pi/180)));
    locationQuery.longitude.$lte = location.lng + (radiusInDegrees * Math.cos(location.lat * (Pi/180)));

    locationQuery.latitude.$gte = location.lat - radiusInDegrees;
    locationQuery.latitude.$lte = location.lat + radiusInDegrees;

    query.location = locationQuery;
}
if (s !== undefined){
    query.name = new RegExp(`^${s}$`, "i");
}
database.Shop.find(query)
    .sort(sort)
    .limit(per_page)
    .skip((page - 1) * per_page)
    .select("name logo status rating _type location")
    .populate("logo")
    .exec((err, shops) => {
        if (err){
            res.status(500);
            return res.json({
                status_code: 500,
                message: "internal server error"
            });
        }
        database.Shop.count(query, (err, count) => {
            res.header("document-count", count);
            let max_pages = Math.ceil(count / per_page);
            res.header("total-pages", max_pages);
            let fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.baseUrl;
            let originalQS = req.query;
            originalQS.page = page;
            originalQS.per_page = per_page;
            if (page < max_pages) {
                let qs = originalQS;
                qs.page = page + 1;
                res.header("next-page", fullUrl + "?" + queryString.stringify(qs));
            }
            if (page > 1 && max_pages > 0) {
                let previous_page = page - 1;
                if (page > max_pages) {
                    previous_page = max_pages;
                }
                let qs = originalQS;
                qs.page = previous_page;
                res.header("previous-page", fullUrl + "?" + queryString.stringify(qs));
            }
            res.header("page", page);
            res.json(shops);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to update your query format. for the nested object, you need to use dot (`.` ) notation. so use like `"location.longitude"` instead of using `{ location:{ latitude:{....`

so you can update your code to build the query like bellow

```
let query = {};
if (location.lat && location.lng) {
    let Pi = Math.PI;
    if (isNaN(radius)) {
        radius = 1000; // radius in meters
    }
    let radiusInDegrees = radius / 111317;


    query["location.longitude"] = {
        $gte: location.lng - (radiusInDegrees * Math.cos(location.lat * (Pi / 180))),
        $lte: location.lng + (radiusInDegrees * Math.cos(location.lat * (Pi / 180)))
    };

    query["location.latitude"] = {
        $gte: location.lat - radiusInDegrees,
        $lte: location.lat + radiusInDegrees
    };
}
if (s !== undefined) {
    query.name = new RegExp(`^${s}$`, "i");
}
```

That will generate query like bellow and should work

```
{
    'location.latitude': { '$gte': 33.626016646154675, '$lte': 33.64398335384532 },
    'location.longitude': { '$gte': 70.88152061196703, '$lte': 70.89647938803296 },
    name: /^انار0$/i
}
```